# Java & Errors in my INSERT Statement

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, sql-insert

I need help on what I am doing wrong, please.

database called renters

addressID is auto-increment from a table called Property, and included in a table called  Renter, I am doing a java assignment.

I connect to the database, and when I try to add a new renter it gives me this error

> Error processing the SQL!java.sql.SQLException: Field 'AddressID' doesn't have a default value
>   Database connection terminated

here is my insert statement:

```
     String addFirstName = txtFirstName.getText();
     String addLastName = txtLastName.getText();
     String addCellPhone = txtCellPhone.getText();
     String addDepositPaid = txtDepositPaid.getText();
     String addDepositAmtPaid = txtDepositAmtPaid.getText();

Statement lstatement = conn.createStatement();

ls_query = "INSERT INTO Renter (FirstName,LastName,CellPhone,DepositPaid,DepositAmtPaid) VALUES('" + addFirstName + "','" + addLastName + "','" + addCellPhone + "','" + addDepositPaid + "'," + addDepositAmtPaid + ")";

myStatement.executeUpdate(ls_query); JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New Renter Added");
```

;

Comment: You should not completely modify the content of your question, that breaks the concept of the site entirely, as now question and answers do not fit together anymore.  If you have a new problem, start a new question (and accept the answer here that best solved your problem).  That's why I rolled back your edits, the new problem should really go in a new question.

Comment: ok thank you for your help, and I'm still having issues. The more I mess with it the more I screw it up.

Comment: i did it again, but changed the subject line and I wasn't thinking that the answers wuld still be here. I flagged it to be deleted , again im really sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the database schema, probably column `AddressID` is marked as `NOT NULL`.  You're trying to insert a record without specifying a value for that column, and as there's no default value specified the insert fails.

So, you can either modify the schema and remove the `NOT NULL` constraint if that makes sense, OR specify a default value for that column, OR provide one with your insert.

But there is another in my opinion ***major*** issue with your code: as you are stringing together the insert statement you're wide open to SQL injections.  The solution is quite simple, use PreparedStatement, a good tutorial can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Head over to [bobby-tables.com](http://bobby-tables.com/), it's a great first introduction to the very frequent problem of SQL injection with recipes on how to avoid them for many languages, including Java.  A great resource!

Answer (score 0):

Add AddressID when using Insert command. In general every non default column and non AutoIncrement column must be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`ls_query = "INSERT INTO Renter (FirstName,LastName,CellPhone,DepositPaid,DepositAmtPaid,AdressId) VALUES('" + addFirstName + "','" + addLastName + "','" + addCellPhone + "','" + addDepositPaid + "','" + addDepositAmtPaid + "','0')";`

EDIT

Im not experienced in java. But looks like the `;` works like in `C#`.

A `INSERT` statement usually ends or delimits with `;` in other words in MySQL says execute from this point.

Can you give this a try?

`ls_query = "INSERT INTO Renter (FirstName,LastName,CellPhone,DepositPaid,DepositAmtPaid,AdressId) VALUES('" + addFirstName + "','" + addLastName + "','" + addCellPhone + "','" + addDepositPaid + "','" + addDepositAmtPaid + "','0');";`

Comment: it still says it, Im really sorry ... I read somewhere you can ut null and that wont work, shows errors

Comment: Is it the same error message ; expected or your first one? I posted a change, give it a try!

Comment: You can edit your question! Just run the inital CREATE TABLE statement you posted, the you are back...but without the data you had.

Comment: Thats because its a foregin key in the other table. It needs a id that exists in the other table its refering to!